How to point a subdomain to google cloud storage bucket
i have a GC storage bucket. I want to point a subdomain to it. lets say my storage bucket url is my-bucket.storage.googleapis.com.
It servers some files under it my-bucket.storage.googleapis.com/files/notes.txt.
i want to have the same file with my sub domain storage.example.com/files/notes.txt.
P.s
I tried adding cname record in my DNS but its not helping.
it returned this response
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>

Also there is already a question answered but this solution is not applicable in my case as i cant change the name of my storage bucket, nor can i create a new one, its already in production and other mutlple services are actively using it.

The name of the bucket shall be the full domain.
for example if you want it to point to subdomain.example.com then the bucket name shall be subdomain.example.com
Additionally you need to make your bucket public by giving AllUsers the role roles/storage.objectViewer
Once you have done both you will need to connect a load balancer to the bucket for this you will need to:

Create a Load Balancer as mentioned in 1
choose the Application Load Balancer (HTTP/HTTPS) type, and set it to be public
choose the location that best fits your usage.
Configure the frontend

Choose the protocol
Create a static IP Adress (consider this one will incur in a cost)
Select a port (443 is recommended so its the HTTPS one)
Create the google managed certificate and include the subdomains will be used on it


Configure the Backend

Create a backend bucket
Choose the bucket



Finally on your registrar add the records to point it to the load balancer
all this is better described in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Yeah but i cant create a new one, iwant to point a domain to the current one.
